# Realm notifications

Tags: java, android, realm

I create listener for new objects. When I recieve new object it has class io.realm.Realm. How to extract values from element?

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object element) {
            Log.i("Debug", String.valueOf(element.getClass()));
        }
    };
```

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications